# Rails 4: Update Model Column on Destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, update-attribute

This is for a ticketing system.

When you close a ticket, theres a column of `resolution`. The user types in the resolution, ie, "this ticket was resolved by xyz". The column is of type textfield, not a string.  So you go to close it and type in some sort of resolution. But that field does not get 'updated' when the ticket is deleted.

**Summary: update the column of resolution on the Ticket model when the ticket is destroyed. Reasoning: the resolution has to be passed to email (via Sendgrid) and SMS (via Twilio). Currently, it'll pass the default value of resolution (whatever that value may be when the ticket is created).**

In the initial ticket creation form, I have `resolution` as a hidden field like so:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :resolution, :value => "No Resolution Provided" %>
```

What I've tried:

In the `ticket.rb` model:

```
before_destroy { self.update_attribute(:resolution, "a hardcoded value here") }
```

So sure that works but that isn't reading from the form, just a hardcoded value. Correct me if I'm wrong but what I'm attempting to do should be done in the controller, correct?

I've tried a `before_action` but haven't had much success. This method does not work when used with a `before_action`:

```
def update_resolution
    @ticket = Ticket.find(params[:id])
    @ticket_res = @ticket.resolution
    @ticket_res.update_attribute(params[:resolution])
end
```

The above creates a redirect loop.

What's the best way to go about this? Any and all input is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Updating a record just prior to deleting it just for some other function that doesn't actually need the record to work doesn't sound like a good way of working to me.

This workflow makes more sense to me:

1. Submit form to controller for resolved ticket, with resolution text
2. Create a background email job with details of the resolution to notify interested parties
3. Create another background twilio job with the SMS detaios to notify interested parties
4. Destroy the ticket (are you sure you won't ever need it again?)

You should read the Rails Guides on background jobs: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html

Whilst not the fastest background job system, delayed job will be the easiest to get started with - https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job

Comment: Yeah, you're 100% right and I've decided to not destroy the tickets. Have set up a custom route/controller action 'close' for handling this. Added a 'completed_at' column for tickets and then set up a scope in ticket.rb for showing tickets on the index page: ie, where `completed_at: nil`. I appreciate the response as you pointed me in the right direction :)

Comment: I would stick with the standard `destroy` action in your controller ... just don't actually destroy the records. Use it to close them and handle closure notifications.